# INImage is broken when user selects item in configurable widget iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, widgetkit

The image displays correctly in the menu that shows up when clicking "Edit Widget":
[image]

But when the item is selected, the image looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe) else {
    return 
}

let image = INImage(imageData: data)
```